# How to add a animated preview from video in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, video, iframe, embed, thumbnails

I'm trying to create a web in Wordpress where I add embed videos in each post with iframe.
These videos are taken from pages like Youtube/Vimeo and to many other similar sites.

I'd like add in the index page (where you can see all the posts with their thumbnails) a animated thumbnail preview like in youtube or other sites.
I'm triying with to many plugins, but none of them works.

It's possible do these? Can I do it in a simple way taking a url iframe from original sites?

Comment: Your question is way too broad...  It's an interesting problem to solve, that's for sure, but my initial research shows too many avenues to pursue. You don't even mention a programming language... For YT videos you could get all its thumbs and create a "jpg -> gif" method. For Vimeo, no idea; for similar sites you'd have to research what they give. What I'm sure is that there's no "simple way" to do this. You're probably better off looking for an online tool, example: http://derraleves.com/how-to-create-animated-gifs-for-your-youtube-videos/

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you for your answer. Sorry for not specifying the question enough. I did not say the language that I used because I thought people would relate Wordpress with php (that is what I am using).